# Delete query when in a loop gives first chance error second time through

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This code in my vb.net controller:

```
 For i = 0 To depToDelete.Count - 1
     cmd.CommandText = "delete from budget.budget_monthlybudgetfees where guid in(@strdepToDelete, @strOtherToDelete);"
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@strdepToDelete", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36).Value = depToDelete(i)
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@strOtherToDelete", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36).Value = otherToDelete(i)
      Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        success = True
      Catch ex As Exception
        success = False
      End Try
  Next
```

I have set the connection string earlier.  The delete query runs first time through but second time it throws a "first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll.  I have tried putting Trim on parameters as per another post suggestion, but still the same error.  I have tried setting cmd.CommandText to "" at beginning of loop but no change.

Comment: There is almost always more to the message - something more specific.  For the code shown though, I'd expect it to crash with more than one Item -  you are adding the same parameters over and over, meaning by iteration 3, you will have 3 `@strdepToDelete` params to account for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you get the error message because you add the parameters on each iteration of the loop. Parameters can be added only once. However, you can of course change their assigned value in the loop like this:

```
cmd.Parameters("@myParameter").Value = "Assign value here"
```

So, just add the parameters before the loop and then only change the value during the loop.

Comment: That did the trick.  thanks.  A new learning to put in my file.

Comment: VB looks like this -- cmd.Parameters("@myParameter").Value = "Assign value here"